# What defines the name of Desktop vs. Arbeitsplatz vs. Schreibtisch in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, configuration

I have a German localized version of Xubuntu 22.04. I have encountered cases, when the desktop was called "Arbeitsplatz" and other cases, where it was called "Schreibtisch".

What is the place where this definition is made?
Which configuration app shall I use when I want to change such a name?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could provide a specific example that we can reproduce. You might be describing a translation bug, or you might be describing differing translations between two applications, or you might be describing something else.

Comment: There might be a translation bug in the comment at the beginning of `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. I have the solution but can't post it here, perhaps because someone has downvoted the question to -1 - although the question is clear: In the past, the localized German directory for the desktop was "Schreibtisch" and it has become "Arbeitsplatz".  Apparently the translations of directories has changed - but in a not consistent manner ultimately resulting in a consequential problem discussed in #1466343.

Comment: I don’t know why you’ve had a downvote - your question seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

The translated file names are defined in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. After first deleting this file and then issuing the command `xdg-user-dirs-update` it became

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run.
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Schreibtisch"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Vorlagen"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Öffentlich"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Bilder"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/"
The line about XDG_DESKTOP_DIR read
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR=“$HOME”
```

In my case, before the deletion, the line with `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` was:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
```

which explains the strange behavior which triggered my question.

It is not sufficient to just change this line to

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Schreibtisch"
```

because one first has to log out and then to log in in order that the changed setting become effective, because `xdg-user-dirs-update` is run very early in the login phase.

The prefix of `user-dirs.dir` says, all changes to it are *retained* at the next startup. But I have observed that they are *reverted*. Has someone stumbled over a language hurdle when writing the description?

`man xdg-user-dirs-update` tells us

"... updates the current state of the file `user-dirs.dir`. If none exists before calling it, then one is created based on the system default values, or falling back to the old non-translated filenames if such directories exists. The list of old directories used are: `~/Desktop`, `~/Templates` and `~/Public`.

...

Additionally, any configured directories that point to non-existing locations are reset by pointing then to the users home directory."

The last sentence probably describes what deleted the name of the second user's desktop directory name from `$XDG_DESKTOP_DIR`.

Unfortunately `man xdg-user-dirs-update` does not tell from where it takes the defaults if the other user specific sources in `~/` don't exist, as it was in my case. Probably it is in one of the paths named in `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`:

`XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/etc/xdg:/etc/xdg`

(surprisingly `/etc/xdg` is named there twice!)

There is a file `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults` which might be the master template effective if no localization has happened. But I could not determine, which file actually makes the localized template for `xdg-user-dirs-update`.

Comment: Does the information in this post answer your question, or is the quesition still open, looking for a satisfactory solution? If the case is the latter, you run the risk that this post will be removed on grounds of being "not an answer". You might consider moving this information up into the question body, where it could serve as further details about your intent (that others already suggested being insufficient).

Comment: I also suggest changing the question's title to "How to permanently override localized strings in Xubuntu 22.04 in the context of XDG_DESKTOP_DIR?"

Comment: I posed two questions. The second one is "Which configuration app shall I use when I want to change such a name?" The last sentence of my answer indicates, that this one is still open: What actually makes the localized template for `xdg-user-dirs-update`? Would heading be better for the whole problem than the current one? - If you have an idea for it, I would add it to my Answer. - Or should I delete my second question from above: Then my answer would be complete and I would add a green hook to it.